# Error 28P01 - Password authentication failed

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio

recently I have started my adventure with databases.
I have managed to install postgreSQL and create simple database.
[image]

I've tried to create simple app which will allow me to view data from DB.
I'm using VS 2017. I have managed to configure DataSource in my WindowsForm (NetFramework) project. Test connection was successful.

[image]

When I try to fill my ListBox with data from table I'm recieving error 28P01 (it seems to mean that I'm using wrong password / username).
It is impossible - im using default account (postgres) and passsword which allowed me to populate DB in datagrip.
Can anyone help me to understand what is going on?

Comment: Read the information in your PostgreSQL database log file.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe my DB logs say nothing about my attempts to connect from VS. They only show my "logins" from datagrip. Does it mean that in generall VS doesn't attempt to connect to my DB at all?

Comment: No, there should be a FATAL error. Perhaps you are trying to connect to a different PostgreSQL database? In PostgreSQL v10, you can `SELECT pg_current_logfile();` to find the current log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys I have managed to work it out. The thing that I did bad was configuration of connection in VS DataSource configuration. I had choosen NOT to include sensitive data into connection string - I had to put it in my code or change setting to INCLUDE it.

I feel so dumb